# What uniform is this French gentleman wearing?

Tags: identification, uniform, french-revolution

Can anyone help me identify the uniform that this gentleman is wearing? [image]

Comment: Have you got any other information about the picture?

Comment: Do you have any prior information to explain the tag "french-revolution" ? Obviously the picture was taken much later...

Comment: I rather suspect the answer is "theatrical".

Comment: The item in the right hand strongly resembles a [drum majors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drum_major_(marching_band)) ceremonial *mace*, perhaps from the French Imperial Guard. [Like here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cf/Soignies_-_Garde_Imp%C3%A9riale_2.JPG/1920px-Soignies_-_Garde_Imp%C3%A9riale_2.JPG)